# Get Return from a dynamic form from javascript to view in django imagefileds

Tags: javascript, django, django-views

I want to get dynamic image upload data from a javascript to my view.py in django my dynamic scrpit

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var id = 1;
        $("#add_more").click(function(){
            var showId = ++id;
            if(showId <=5)
            {
                $(".input-files").append('<input type="file" name="file_upload-'+showId+'">');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and my view and model

```
img_dokans = ArrayField(models.URLField(max_length=200), blank=True, null=True)
```

Suggest me my view from a html form how can i integrate script to django so i can get the files which later i ll upload to S3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all the uploaded files in request.FILES, the key is the element's name so you can save them all.